# How to convert Kinect ColorSpacePoint in Unity WorldPoint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, kinect-sdk

**PreInformation:** Using Kinect v2 and Unity3D v5.4

**Background:** I have programmatically created `GameObject` objects, like Cubes and Spheres. The Position of these `GameObject` items I'm setting with: `gameObject.transform.position`. With the Kinect I'm detecting the current `Handposition` of the user. What I want to do is to check if the `Handposition` is near the position of the created `GameObject`.

**Problem:** My Problem right now is how I can convert the `handposition`. The `handposition` I converted from `CameraSpacePoint` to `ColorSpacePoint`:

```
ColorSpacePoint csPoint=_Sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToColorSpace(handPosition);
```

How can I convert these `ColorSpacePoint` objects now to the Unity positions(`transform.position`)?

Comment: Why do you convert it from CameraSpace to ColorSpace? Sounds like you want the 3D position of the hand, which is the one in CameraSpace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cspoint and transform.position are both two different types of vectors: cspoint is a 2d vector, transform.position a 3d vector.

So, what you'll need is a convert function.

```
Vector3 toUnityVector3(ColorSpacePoint point)
{
   return new Vector3(point.x,point.y,0); //swap the parameters around as you see fit
}
```